# Adding a Twitpic function using oAuth

Tags: objective-c, ios, oauth, twitpic

Hey I'm working on a Twitter Application based of the source code from iCodeblog. 
( http://icodeblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/iCodeOauth.zip ).

I was wondering how I could add a TwitPic function to the app without the user having to sign in again just to upload a picture.

When the app launches the first time the user will be provided with a login page thanks to the consumer key etc so I want it to use the same that info for the TwitPic function too so the user won't have to sign in again.

Hope this makes sense

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried https://github.com/Gurpartap/GSTwitPicEngine yet?

It'll accept your already retrieved oauth token and let you upload images without any password reauthentication.

Hope it helps.